# Developing websites for Kindle

Tags: css, html, mobile, media-queries, kindle

I've recently entertained the idea of designing and developing a special mobile version of my website for the experimental web browser in Amazon Kindle. **Not** Kindle Fire, but the e-Ink ones.

However, I've failed to find any real resources on the web on this subject matter. I grant you, the market share for the Kindle browser must be so abysmal that most webmasters shouldn't even come to think of worrying about it. Even so, my website is ebook-centered, so I think a Kindle-friendly design would make sense for this case.

So I ask you, what are the considerations on making a Kindle-friendly website in your opinion?

What is/are the screen resolution(s) and DPI I should design for? How do I detect Kindle (but not Kindle Fire) via JS/CSS media queries?

What browser engine do they use? What is its HTML5 and CSS3 capabilities? AJAX? JavaScript timeouts? jQuery animations? Is there an emulator/equivalent for the PC I could test it with?

Only ever owning a Kindle Keyboard, what are the differences between the different iterations of Kindles (again not Kindle Fire), in regards screen properties and technical capabilities? Are there other electronic paper readers (like Nook, Sony Reader and what have you) that I should consider supporting? Do they even have web browsers?

Are there any other technical, design or philosophical questions I should take into account when creating a site for the purpose of displaying on an e-Ink screen?

Comment: Woah. That is a lot of questions. You would probably be better served choosing a single thing you are actually having a problem with (like browser detection) an asking about that. This question as it stands is too broad.

Comment: I don't necessarily need an answer for all these questions. I'm just frustrated that virtually no other resource exists for this topic (on StackOverflow nor Google), and I thought instead of spamming 12 different questions about a topic that's hardly of interest to many, I thought to centralize it to one. **The basic question still is; what do I need to care about when making a Kindle optimized site?**

Comment: I get that. I'm still saying that *this question is too broad*. You will do much better with this problem by trying to make something, and then asking about particular problems as you encounter them.

Comment: About the last question (non-technical considerations), you will probably have more luck (and generate more interesting answers) in http://ux.stackexchange.com/ and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: did you find any resource in the last 2 years? =)